# 1.4V instead of 0V when Arduino signals a LOW

Tags: stepper-motor, multiplexer, arduino-uno

I have motor controlling mechanism as the one shown in the image. I'm controlling the direction of a motor controller from three different sources. `DIR1` and `DIR2` form two of these sources and at any point in time one of them is the controlling source and is selected using the MUX. The third source `OUT_2` is essentially connected to the motor controllers through the optocoupler directly and this source gets priority over the earlier two sources. `OUT_2` is generated by an Arduino. In the real world implementation of this, when the external MCU signals `OUT_2` to be LOW, I see 1.47V at `OUT` instead of 0V. Why is this and how do I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've got two outputs driving the same line. If one pulls high, and one pulls low, they short each other out.

The internal resistance of both drivers will result in a mid-level voltage on the signal line. Typically closer to 0V than VDD as NMOS transistors (used to pull down) are typically stronger than PMOS (used to pull up).

How you resolve it depends on how your opto-coupler is driven (hence we always ask for a proper schematic). If you connect it from VDD (anode) to signal (cathode), then you just need to make both outputs open drain (i.e. they never pull high, only low or floating). Alternatively use a AND gate which will drive the opto-coupler high only when both inputs are high.

Comment: Thanks! Using an AND gate is not feasible since the two sources even though are driven on the same line are independent of each other. Not sure what you mean by making both outputs open drain. How would I do that? One is the digital pin of an MCU and other other a MUX output pin. The optocoupler schematic is shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/1ja0nUL.png).

Comment: You could also use two diodes to do a wired AND.